# There are uncommitted transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN    

   INSERT INTO dbo.Student
     (FirstName, LastName)
   VALUES 
     ('Jon','Ye')

   IF XACT_STATE() = 0
     COMMIT TRAN

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  IF XACT_STATE() <> 1
    ROLLBACK TRAN
  ELSE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END CATCH

RETURN
GO
```

Error Message:

> There are uncommitted transactionS.

I only see results when I close SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here

```
   IF XACT_STATE() = 0
        COMMIT TRAN
```

XACT_STATE() only returns 0 if no active user transaction exists. Due to the open transaction started by BEGIN TRAN, XACT_STATE must be returning 1 and the COMMIT TRAN consequently does not  execute. You should be checking for a return value of 1